# Язык C, перекрытие идентификаторов

Tags: c

Подскажите, происходит ли перекрытие идентификатора в следующем случае:

```
void f1(T _t)
{
    void f2(T _t)
    {
       _t = 3;// Используется f2()::_t?
    }

    f2(_t);
}
```

И если да, то в какой части **Стандарта** искать описание этого правила?

Comment: Ничего подобного в стандарте нет и быть не может. Это даже отдаленно не похоже на С. В языке С не допускается вложенных определений функций. Поэтому вопрос о каком-то "перекрытии идентификаторов", да еще и с упоминанием стандарта языка (!), совершенно бессмыслен

Comment: Между прочим: область видимости переменных из **f1()** не закрывается в **f2()**. В вашем примере можно вообще не пользоваться передачей аргументов.

Comment: @Ant, **GNU C** позволяет и вложенные функции, и **for (int i**, и массивы нулевой длины, и много всего полезного (и опасного ;)). Это **MS** забросили свой **C** компилятор на уровне **C89**. По этой причине > 95% сишного кода сейчас пишется на **gcc/MinGW**.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, я знаю, просто привел пример, чтобы мой вопрос был ясен. Обычно я использую вложенные функции без аргументов, учитывая, что вложенная функция имеет доступ ко всему, что находится в области ее определения (или объявления?). Но тут возникла идея реализовать кое-какую интересную *вертуху*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers**
>   If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the
>   inner scope) will be a strict subset of the scope of the other entity
>   (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates
>   the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the
>   outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

C99 – ISO 9899:1999 [WG14 draft version N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)